# How to add Random time stamps in zoomable area chart in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I want to plot some data against time with zoom in area chart. Problem is it will not contain reading for every sec basis.

```
pointInterval: intervals,
pointStart:startDate,
data:energyData
```

I am using above thing in highcharts. when i give it reading for every sec it plots it right. but now i want to plot for random time. i don't have readings for every  sec instead i have it for 30 sec each.

In this case it plots x-axis wrong. can i give it data like

```
[time1,value1],[time2,value2],....
```

Comment: Could you recreate your example in the jsfiddle ?

Comment: thanks but i have used some other method.